# Merge single-line .txt files

Tags: r

I have several .txt files made up of just a single long line.
The structure of each file is the following:

> LAT1 LONG1 T1 T2 T3... LAT2 LONG2 T1 T2 T3...

And so on.

I would like to merge all of them in a single `.txt` file.

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Comment: Lets make an example with two txt files:
Each file is composed by a single line. The first two numbers in the line are LAT LONG coordinates and then a list of hourly temperatures in Kelvin:

File 1 
-6.85 34.25 289.58 288.69 287.58 288.75 291.5 293.85
File 2
7.45 36.35 277.7 276.48 276.1 280.52 287.13 286.06

I would like to create a file merging the two files above

File tot
-6.85 34.25 289.58 288.69 287.58 288.75 291.5 293.85 7.45 36.35 277.7 276.48 276.1 280.52 287.13 286.06

Comment: Worg, can you just `cat * > newfile` on the command line? Or perhaps in R (not necessarily more efficient) `system2("cat", shQuote(filelist), stdout = "outfile.txt")`? (Better said: why does this need to be done in R?)

Comment: the title says usin r at the time of this post - can you be more specific

Comment: The files I am working on are many and quite long. I would like to avoid any possible mistake. That is why I am trying to use an authomatic code in R to do the job. I am a newby in R and in any other programming language. I thought it was an easy task even for a newby. But I realised it is not.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments it would be very easy to do this in a Unix shell (`cat * > newfile`), but if you want to do it in R it could go something like this:

```
my_files <- c("file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt")
## or my_files  <- list.files(pattern=".*\\.txt") [or appropriate pattern]
outstr <- ""
for (f in my_files) {
    outstr <- paste(outstr,readLines(f))
}
writeLines(outstr, "out_file.txt")
```

There are many, many variations depending on the details (e.g. you want newline characters between the data from each file; each file has a header row, which you only want to include for the first file; etc. etc.)

Comment: Dear Ben, 
I have tried the code you have provided me and it basically works.
However it displays me this error. 

1: In readLines(f) : incomplete final line found on 'file1.txt'
2: In readLines(f) : incomplete final line found on 'file2.txt'

Furthermore considering that "file1.txt" is composed by 1 2 3 and "file2.txt" is composed by 4 5 6,
Then the output of "out_file.txt" is 
 1 2 3  4 5 6
I would like to remove the first space and the additional space after number 3. 
Sorry for not being able to explain me better.

Comment: (1) those are warnings, not errors, and can probably be ignored; (2) can you please edit your question to show your example input and desired output?